# Ruby File.read vs. File.gets

Tags: ruby, file-io

If I want to append the contents of a src file into the end of a dest file in Ruby, is it better to use:

```
 while line = src.gets do
```

or

```
 while buffer = src.read( 1024 )
```

I have seen both used and was wondering when should I use each method and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One is for reading "lines", one is for reading *n* bytes.

While byte buffering might be faster, a lot of that may disappear into the OS which likely does buffering anyway. IMO it has more to do with the context of the read--do you want lines, or are you just shuffling chunks of data around?

That said, a performance test in your specific environment may be helpful when deciding.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'm more "shuffling chunks or data around" and don't necessarily care about lines. Performance I do care about. I'll probably go with read which seems more suitable in this scenario. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

You have a number of options when reading a file that are tailored to different situations.

Read in the file line-by-line, but only store one line at a time:

```
while (line = file.gets) do
  # ...
end
```

Read in all lines of a file at once:

```
file.readlines.each do |line|
  # ...
end
```

Read the file in as a series of blocks:

```
while (data = file.read(block_size))
  # ...
end
```

Read in the whole file at once:

```
data = file.read
```

It really depends on what kind of data you're working with. Generally `read` is better suited towards binary files, or those where you want it as one big string. `gets` and `readlines` are similar, but `readlines` is more convenient if you're confident the file will fit in memory. Don't do this on multi-gigabyte log files or you'll be in for a world of hurt as your system starts swapping. Use `gets` for situations like that.

Answer (score 2):

`gets` will read until the end of the line based on a separator

`read` will read n bytes at a time

It all depends on what you are trying to read.

It may be more efficient to use `read` if your src file has unpredictable line lengths.